# Security Level and Firewall submenu missing in Administration menu in centos 6.4

Tags: centos

I downloaded the full Centos 6.4 [DVD1.iso](http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/centos/6.4/isos/x86_64/) and after installation, I see very few entries in Administration menu.
Specifically, I am missing the "Security Level and Firewall submenu".

How can I get these entries? Do I need to install any extra package?

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but how about:

```
# yum install system-config-firewall
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install following rpm

```
#yum install system-config-securitylevel
```

Comment: That gives a different UI from default multi-tab window I have seen in other systems. [See here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Image:Centos_firewall.jpg) .. not sure if this is just due to different OS versions